Is there a way to mix splitting faces and edges?
I've got this Demogorgon-like creature I want to split the head to create the petal-like flaps of its face.
I'm wanting to effectively peel this single mesh into a fan-like, or petal-like mesh. I figure I need each edge to duplicate its vertices at each end except for the basal end (towards the body).
Basically, how do I peel this banana? I've tried with my limited knowledge and done some searching, but I perhaps cannot phrase it correctly.
The dark orange lines are marked UV seems to express the boundaries of the peel/petal/flay

Select Edge Rings:

Split Faces by Edges:

Select the top vertices - now that they are split you can't use an ⎇ Altclick, but you can go to wireframe view mode and drag-select. Then enable O Proportional Editing, ⎇ AltS shrink/flatten outwards, GZ Move down. Obviously you can adjust Proportional Editing settings for a better effect but that's the gist of it:


That is exactly what I had asked for
Thank you for creating such a well-constructed answer!
